# Alcatraz - Xcode command line tools are not currently installed

Tags: macos, terminal, xcode

I'm managing Xcode plug-ins via [Alcatraz](http://alcatraz.io/).

Everything was alright until I installed and then uninstalled Git following instruction in the uninstalled.sh file in official git.zip file:

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/git/   
sudo rm /etc/paths.d/git   
sudo rm /etc/manpaths.d/git
```

I have no idea what I've done with git would affect Alcatraz.
Once I click Package Manager in Xcode I get this error:

[image]

Even re-install the Alcatraz it's still there.

**Update**

I did install the Command Line Tool following [Xcode Command Line Tool tutorial](http://railsapps.github.io/xcode-command-line-tools.html)

Here's the message I got:

```
myMacBook-Air:~ me$ gcc --version   
Configured with:--prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1  
Apple LLVM version 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.72) Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.5.0 
Thread model: posix
```

The Warning still pops up.

How could I fix this?

Comment: Did you (re)install the command line tools as the error message suggests?

Comment: @patrix nope ...did nothing with the command line tool.

Comment: Then maybe you could do this as this seems to be the recommended way to solve the problem?!

Comment: @patrix I found nothing to download in the Preference Downloads section. Also I did install the Command Line Tool via Terminal, please see the update. Error keeps showing up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After installing *[git-2.5.3-intel-universal-mavericks](http://sourceforge.net/projects/git-osx-installer/files/git-2.5.3-intel-universal-mavericks.dmg/download)* you have at least three git executables on your Mac:

- /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/git (v2.3.8 (Apple Git-58))
- /usr/local/git/bin/git (v2.5.3)
- /usr/bin/git (which is a stub only)

If you've followed the instructions in the *README.txt* inside the *git-2.5.3-intel-universal-mavericks.dmg* you probably renamed the original git stub:

```
sudo mv /usr/bin/git /usr/bin/git-system
```

Renaming or removing the stub already breaks Alcatraz.

You may now whether rename git-system:

```
sudo mv /usr/bin/git-system /usr/bin/git
```

or reinstall git-2.5.3-intel-universal-mavericks and link the GIT-git to /usr/bin:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/git/bin/git /usr/bin
```

to fix your issue.

Comment: Super effective! I installed git via official dmg file, and typing `which git` showed me `/usr/local/git/bin/git`. I did nothing with the file name. Anyway, thanks for saving my life!